# How do I fix the error "To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated."?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

At first I have built database successfully:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi2zs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi2zs.png)

Then I wanted to add column and change data order between 1st row and 2nd row.

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuj24.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuj24.png)

But I have failed and got an error:

> To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated

How do I solve this?

In addition, this is my first-time in code-first programming.

I have removed the table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. But I still got the same error.

Comment: I tested with adding your columns like you describe but with no error. What commands are you using to update the new database?

Answer (score 1):

since you've already made changes to your model by adding a new property DisplayOrder, you should create a new migration to apply these changes to the database. Use the following command in the Package Manager

```
Add-Migration AddDisplayOrderToMasterItem
```

once it is done update your database using the following command

```
Update-Database
```